# Sybase DB error 277 in while loop after migration

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I am new to Sybase products.

The application was run on Windows XP connect with the SYC adaptive server, written in Powerbuilder 10.5.

Once I migrate it to PB12.6, and move the whole DB and application to win 7, one of the stored procedures throws an error 277:

> There was a transaction active when exiting the stored procedure '%.*s'. The temporary table '%.*s' was dropped in this transaction either explicitly or implicitly.

in the procedure

```
...set initiate value of a and b...
...do sth...

print 'check point 1' 
while (a=0) and b>0
begin
print 'check point 2'
...do sth...
end
print 'check point 3'
... do sth...
```

I found that both a and b = 0, after print 'check point 1', it shows 'return status=-1' then error 277.

No 'check point 2' or 'check point 3' can be shown

Has anyone experienced this before? Why the while loop become so strange?

I have checked commit / rollback statement exist before any return

And the stored procedure is no problem in PB10.5 running on Windows XP.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You reviewed the following documentation? http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc00729_1500/html/errMessageAdvRes/BABHEJIB.htm

Comment: Yes, but I checked the begin transaction , commit , row back statement should be no problem, and the sp stop at the while statement make me confuse......

Comment: @BruceArmstrong say: "What do you have the AutoCommit setting set to? You have to turn off PBs transaction control and handle that manually when there is DDL involved.". With the same error on this site: http://nntp-archive.sybase.com/nntp-archive/action/article/%3C40ec3240$1@forums-2-dub%3E